# Horizontal RecyclerViews scrolling the same dx inside Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a vertical recyclerview with a horizontal recyclerview in eatch item.

when I scrollBy like 100 pixels in dx, in all visible horizontal recycler views, everything is ok, but when I scroll down, the "new" horizontal recycler views appear in dx 0, like no scroll every occurred.

Is there a way to scroll all horizontal recyclers the same distance?
Maybe keep the dx and apply it when the view is recycled or recreated? Or move to position 0 and then scroll the distance?

Example:

there are 5 visible items, in the vertical recycler view,

i scroll horizontally, scrollBy(100,0) in all visible items, scroll 100 pixels right,

I then scroll the verticall recycler, and the new items appering show the "new" recyclerview in the position 0,

i need all the horizontal recyclers to be with the 100 dx scrolled, i will try to put images

PS:
gif, old way without recycler and very slow

https://giphy.com/gifs/3o6ZtqPlYl0j7wIi0U

in that gif i can scroll horizontally, and then verticall and every line is sincronised (no recycler views), in my version, when i scroll down, the fisrt item is always the red (red is first item)

Comment: can you share an image to make the issue more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can define an [OnScroll Listene](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html)r instance, and for each horizontal RecyclerView [add](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)) the OnScrollListener instance.

whenever a recycler view is scrolled, notify the other recycler views via an observer pattern implementation (listeners) such that each recycler view invokes its [scrollBy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) method

Comment: i'm doing that to do the scrollBy in the visible items; 
                      
for(int i = firstVisiblePosition; i <= lastVisiblePosition; i++) {
                RecyclerParentHolder holder = (RecyclerParentHolder) parentRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                holder.itemRecycler.scrollBy(dx, 0);
            }

...........
how can I do that for all the recyclers? the ones that are not 'loaded' in the vertical recycler?

Comment: You can define the listeners in your recycle view adapter onBindViewHolder() method

Comment: i'm gona try this method, i will update with results

Comment: for now, i'm unable to do it, the horizontal recycler not visible views are not scrolling, they "dont existe" yet because the recycler optimizations. I scrollBy like 500 dx in the visible items, when i scroll down and the new recyclers apear, they are scrolled 0 dx, maybe i should save like an index for when the new horizontal recycler item apear and apply it

Comment: Yes, that will be a good idea, save the current scroll position in a member varuable in the adapter, and scroll the recycler view to that position in onBindViewHolder()

Comment: it worked as we talk, i save a global index of pixels moved and save the pixels moved in each recycler, I then scroll the recyclers for the diference; i canot accept your anwser as correct I guess because it is incomplete

Comment: Glad to hear that, as for the answer, it's up to you, you can accept it if you feel it inspired you to solve your problem.